# How To Enable/Disable Battery Saver With PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, power-management

PowerShell can be used to change power plans when moving from AC to battery or vice versa, but can PowerShell enable/disable the Battery Saver option?

[image: Battery Saver]

Comment: I do know that there are a few alternative options to interact with this like RPA, AutoIt, or Auto HotKey, but I'm looking for a purely PowerShell option.

Comment: Don't add information in comments please. There's an EDIT button to make it easy to add information to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543738/how-to-enable-disable-windows-10-battery-saver-in-program). Powershell itself can't really do this, but it can run `powercfg` for you like so:

```
powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_ENERGYSAVER ESBATTTHRESHOLD 100
powercfg /setactive scheme_current
```

This sets the "Turn Battery Saver on automatically at x%" setting in "Battery Saver Settings". You can set it back to default by changing `100` to `20` (default on my laptop) and running it again.